# SSRS ReportViewer default Zoom in IE11 (and Firefox)

Tags: reporting-services, zooming, reportviewer

I have this SSRS ReportViewer control on my page. Because the font is too small, I have to change default zoom to ZoomPercent="150". This

(1) works perfect in Chrome

(2) has no effect in Firefox

(3) totally messed up in IE11 - the report flow out and my other input controls/buttons (code not shown here) which lies above this report control cannot be seen anymore.

My code for the reportviewer is as follows. Please help me, is there any problem with my code or is this a problem of reportviewer?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="ReportViewerPanel" runat="server">
            <div class="reportViewerContainer">
                <rsweb:ReportViewer
                    ID="ReportViewer1"
                    runat="server"
                    Font-Names="Calibri"
                    Font-Size="8pt"
                    ProcessingMode="Remote"
                    WaitMessageFont-Names="Calibri"
                    WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt"
                    SizeToReportContent="true"
                    ShowZoomControl="false"
                    ZoomMode="Percent"
                    ZoomPercent="150"                        
                    Height="100%"
                    Width="100%"
                    AsyncRendering="false"
                    CssClass="reportViewerControl" />
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnRunReport" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the similar issues with the print and the zoom feature when using IE11, Fire Fox, and Chrome.

(**Update**) *I was told by a Microsoft representative to update the version of my ReportViewer Control as I was using 10.0. Updating to anything >10.0 seems to have fixed my problem.*

The features are disabled when using any of the above because of compatibility issues with scripting/ActiveX not being properly supported by the FireFox and Chrome.

I believe the control determines the browser you are using is not IE it will not render the controls to prevent unexpected behavior because if the lack of ActiveX support. This can be seen when you compare the HTML of a page using IE8 and that of either IE11, FF, Chrome you'll see that the HTML for a zoom drop down control will show up in the IE8 browser and not in the others.

As for IE11 it presents itself as a Mozilla browser. eg:  "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
so when the control see's this it wont generate any of the controls believing the browser can't support it, even though IE11 should certainly be able of doing so. This should be brought up to Microsoft.

However I did try adjusting the ZoomPercentage in my environment and it did work in IE11 and Chrome. Firefox didn't do anything, I believe it's just the way the Control interacts with each browser.

Here is another [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d9f2b692-929e-4279-97f5-2ceaa55ef17e/print-search-button-not-visible-in-reportviewer-control-in-firefox?forum=sqlreportingservices) with someone from Microsoft answering about other browsers.

[Browser Support for ReportViewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251673%28VS.80%29.aspx)
"The ReportViewer Web server control is used to embed report functionality in an ASP.NET Web application. The type of browser used to view the application determines the kind of functionality that you can provide in a report. Use the table provided in this topic to find out which of the supported browsers are subject to report functionality restrictions."

The page mentions that the following wont be supported by other browsers
The following features are not supported in third-party browsers:

- Document map
- Searching within the report
- Zoom
- Fixed table headers
- The progress indicator for report processing (a green spinning wheel) is not available for server reports, or for locally processed reports that are configured for asynchronous processing.